# Play notification audio sound in xcode console but not on iPod

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, cordova, beep

I'm developing an HTML5 app using Sencha Touch 2.2.1 and Phonegap 2.7.0

I'm using navigator.notification.beep(1) to play a sound, I have the beep.wav file in the www root directory and in my xcode console I see

`2014-04-24 12:42:13.358 PolliniTouch[465:907] Playing audio sample 'beep.wav'
2014-04-24 12:42:14.644 PolliniTouch[465:907] Finished playing audio sample`

But on the iPod the beep is not played

Comment: Is the device muted?  And what iPod generation is it?

Comment: @nhgrif the device isn't muted I and have problem with iPod 4 and iPod 5